# Referencing SV nodes from Graph Editor Drivers

Tags: drivers, graph-editor, sverchok

This I'm sure is a backwards approach and probably not needed so not possible. Still I was wondering how to if possible as it should be...

Having added a driver to for example an object's location y, that comes from the location x of another object. I was able to add a driver modifier "Expanded Polynomial" and do simple multiple expression etc.

I then noted one can change the Driver from Blender's Transform Channel to a 'Single Property' which is symbolized by the SV (red+white Spring) Icon.

Then the property node of type "Node Tree" can be selected, which in turn means I can select an SV Node Tree by name from the popup list, (which defaults to NodeTree).

Remaining unset yet is the 'Path' value. I had attempted to add a simple Formula2Node there too (similar to the modifiers mentioned earlier, just to test multiplying etc).

I tried referencing the SV (Formula2Node) node's result via nodes['Formula'].result in various ways with no luck.

I do understand I can use a 'Set Property' node and don't need to use that Graph Editor (Drivers tab and 'N' inspector panel's) Drivers route/way, but I wondered if there is a way to reference the SV NodeTree nodes result values from an 'outside' place like that what it might be. (I also tried results[0], results.1 etc. but that didn't do anything either.)

Is there some kind of other output node or just an inspector node you'd use to potentially reference the value?

I'm sure there's a more complicated example where this is desirable but this is just a simple example for testing and asking the question.

Comment: I've earned a TumbleWeed Badge for this one.